# Openstack Can't find or reach Networks in Dashboard page

Tags: python, ubuntu, openstack, devstack

I'm totally new to Openstack. I installed openstack through Devstack on a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine in VirtualBox. Openstack version is Mitaka. After installation, I successfully logged in to Openstack dashboard using "admin" account, but after I created an instance, when I tried to check the Network Topology, I found there was no "Network" tab in the side bar.

Then I tried to access the network part by access `x.x.x.x/dashboard/networks` directly, but it said that:

> "You don't have permission to access the resource: /dashboard/project/networks. Login as different user or go back to homepage", "Unauthorised, please try login again".

I don't know what to do, I already logged in as admin and successfully created an instance, why this happen?

How to fix this?

[Dashboard side menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36dI1.png)

[Login error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynWzJ.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default devstack doesn't use neutron, so it will not have the services installed to use that portion of the API.

If you want to use Devstack, which can be painful to modify you can find the instructions here.

[Devstack with Newtron](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/NeutronDevstack)

If you are looking to POC OpenStack or test against the API I highly recommend you try the OpenStack-Ansible method which is less geared to testing and is more modern and very usable for a production installation.

[Openstack-Ansible quick start](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/openstack-ansible/developer-docs/quickstart-aio.html)